# Stanford NLP: punctuation error identification

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I've just started working with Stanford NLP core.

My problem is that many of the sentences in my corpus do not end with a period (full stop).

Frankly, a bit of string parsing with regular expressions could probably fix the issue, but with some degree of error.

I am curious as to whether Stanford NLP can identify missing periods.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `edu.stanfordn.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor` can be used to split paragraphs into sentences, though I am not sure how well it works without proper punctuation.

There are many other sentence-level tokenizers which you can use to preprocess your corpus , check out NLTK's [nltk.tokenize.punkt module](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.punkt) which uses a ML algorithm to make sentence tokens in the absence of good  capitalization/punctuation.